# Using a let to return if receiver is null for error case

Tags: kotlin

```
Kotlin 1.2.50
```

I have the following provided dependency that will create a MovieListItemDecorator and in the constructor it will pass a drawable. However, the getDrawable method can return a nullable:

i.e.

```
@Nullable
public static final Drawable getDrawable(@NonNull Context context, @DrawableRes int id)
```

I am thinking what can I do the case of the getDrawable returning a null value: I have specified 2 cases below. But if the getDrawable does return null I don't want to pass that in the constructor of the `MovieItemDecorator()`

1)

```
@MovieListScope
    @Provides
    fun provideMovieItemDecorator(context: Context): MovieItemDecorator {
        var drawable: Drawable by Delegates.notNull()

        ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.blue_border)?.let {
            drawable = it
        }

        return MovieItemDecorator(drawable)
    }
```

2)

```
 @MovieListScope
    @Provides
    fun provideMovieItemDecorator(context: Context): MovieItemDecorator {
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.blue_border)?.let {
           return MovieItemDecorator(it)
        } ?: {
            return MovieItemDecorator(....) /* what to return here */
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to understand your problem but I am guessing in the end you want a MovieDecorator.

If this MovieItemDecorator requires a drawable parameter, then you must have a drawable (say ColorDrawable) for the case of null

```
@MovieListScope
    @Provides
    fun provideMovieItemDecorator(context: Context) : MovieItemDecorator {
        val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.blue_border) ?: ColorDrawable() 
        return MovieItemDecorator(drawable as Drawable)
    }
```